# jquery unbind event handlers from an event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this code

```
// define event handlers
$("a.ajax").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var $el = $(this); 
    $.get($el.prop("href"), function(response) {
       $el.trigger("success.aliAjax", [$el, response]); 
    });
});

// define event handlers
var Handlers = function () {
};
Handlers.prototype.redirect = function (event, $el, response) {
    if (response && response.location) {
    //    now i have to redirect and disable "Handlers.prototype.success" event handler
        window.location.href = response.location;
    }
};
Handlers.prototype.success = function (event, $el, response) {
    alert("success");
};

// listen for events
$(document).on('success.aliAjax', Handlers.prototype.redirect);
$(document).on('success.aliAjax', Handlers.prototype.success);
```

so, my problem is how can i disable "Handlers.prototype.success" event handler in "Handlers.prototype.redirect" event handler if the conditions provided

here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bomz432c/)

Comment: jquery off http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: i tried but that was not worked

Comment: $(document).off('success.aliAjax')

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$(document).off('success.aliAjax');
```

Change `$("a.ajax").click(...` into `$("a.ajax").on('click', function...`
then you can use `$("a.ajax").off("click")`

EDIT:

Is that what you want? [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bomz432c/1/)

Comment: Edited my answer, maybe you need to turn the click event off.

Comment: i just added at end of question

Comment: Dont know what you want to archiev, but i updated the fiddle.

Comment: did you see the console ? handlers.success is runing, still

Comment: I still don´t know what your goal is. new [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bomz432c/3/)

Comment: the goal is to remove the listener at once, not the second time. If you click your link (https://jsfiddle.net/bomz432c/1/) 2nd, 3rd and 4th time - only one `console.log` will be outputed :) but the first click outputs two

Comment: my guess would be that jQuery prioritizes `.on`... if there are `.off()`s in the `.on()` handlers - they will be executed after `.on()`s. does it make sense? That's why it executes both functions even if one of them contains an `.off()`

Comment: .on()s were first in the queue, so to say :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) with the handler. Like so:

```
$(document).off('success.aliAjax', Handlers.prototype.redirect);
$(document).off('success.aliAjax', Handlers.prototype.success);
```